# The Property "inlineXml" can only be set once

Tags: wpf, xaml, avalondock

**Multiple LayoutDocument inside LayoutDocumentPane**
Gives me error - message: "The Property "inlineXml" can only be set once".

Also try using with "LayoutDocumentPaneGroup", gets same error

```
     <xcad:DockingManager x:Name="DockManager">
                <xcad:DockingManager.Theme>
                    <xcad:MetroTheme/>
                </xcad:DockingManager.Theme>

                <xcad:LayoutRoot>
                    <xcad:LayoutPanel>
                            <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                            <xcad:LayoutDocument Title="Exp1">
                                <TextBox x:Name="TxtInput1">                                          
                                 </TextBox>
                            </xcad:LayoutDocument>
                            <xcad:LayoutDocument Title="Exp2">
                                <TextBox x:Name="TxtInput2">                                          
                                 </TextBox>
                            </xcad:LayoutDocument>
                            </xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                      </xcad:LayoutPanel>
                 </xcad:LayoutRoot>
            </xcad:DockingManager>
```

Any idea what am missing?

Comment: Sorted out I was running my solution in x64. When building a new Solution in x86 from Configuration Manager, it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Avalon Dock 2.9/3.0 and the project set to .Net Framework 4.5.1

Changed .NET Framework to 4.6.1 fixed the issue

Comment: I can see the same issue but I am already using 4.7.2. Any idea what's the root cause for this?